# PySimpleGUI update filepath only when new path is chosen

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I made a GUI with PySimpleGUI where the user has the option to change the standard paths, which will be used in the program. I first defined my standard paths as strings, and then later the user can change them with the help of sg.IN and sg.FolderBrowse fields.

Here the Code:

```
stdPath1 = "PathToFolder1"
stdPath2 = "PathToFolder2"

layout = 
[
        [
            sg.Text("optional new Path for Folder1:", size=(30, 1)),
            sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key='-Folder1-'),
            sg.FolderBrowse(),
        ],
        [
            sg.Text("optional new Path for Folder2:", size=(30, 1)),
            sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-Folder2-"),
            sg.FolderBrowse()
        ],
        [sg.Button("Start")],
]

window = sg.Window("PrgmName", layout)

while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Exit":
            break
        elif event == "Start":
            # start Program 
        elif event == "-Folder1-":
            stdPath1 = values[event]+"/"
        elif event == "-Folder2-":
            stdPath2 = values[event]+"/"


window.close()
```

This works fine, however sometimes my program returns NONE.
I think this happens when the user clicks the button to choose a new path but closes the Browse window without selecting a new path. Then the event is also triggered, which results in a NONE value being given to my path variable. This of course leads to problems later in the program.

Therefore I would like to only update the FolderPath when a path is actually chosen, not when the button is clicked, but I don't know how to do this.
My only idea would be to add something like "if values[event] is not NONE then pass the new path, otherwise continue to use the stdpath". Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think your question is slightly off-topic here and leads to opinion based answers. However, I also do think that there is nothing wrong with a condition above your business logic. For once that is what they made for, [control flow](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) and as topping all your other condition won't be compared against, this will save resources and time. You might think about sharing a working example to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272438/python-tkinter-periodic-table-of-chemical-elements), if you feel comfortable with it.

Comment: BTW, I think if you rephrase your question that focus on the part where it fails. E.g. *I want to know why it returns `None` sometimes and also how to fix it efficiently when it can't be avoided* you should be on-topic to [so]..

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I changed my question slightly, it should be on topic now :)

Comment: Basically, there's no value `None` for an Input element, should be only string. Maybe the `event` is not the key of an Input element. Input element won't be updated and no event generated when you click `Cancel` when browse the files or folder. Try to upgrade your PySimpleGUI from GitHub.

Comment: Sorry, I am not entirely sure if I understand your suggestion. Do you mean the clicking cancel is not the problem, but something else is generating the NONE error? Also, I am using pycharm, so the installation of PySimpleGUI is done in the background, I just need to find the module within Pycharm and klick install. It should be the newest version.

Comment: @Carina Click `Install` just install most update release version, there's another non-release version with most update by `Upgrade from Github`.